# how to get a result without brackets in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a function which merges two sorted lists (a, b) into one sorted (c). If given lists have different lengths I need to insert the rest of the longest into the list c. But the way I did it - it gives the result with brackets inside the list c (for instance if a = [1,3,5] and b = [2,4,6] then the function returns [1,2,3,4,5,[6]]. How can I get rid of those brackets?

here`s my code

```
def merge(a,b):
c = []
i = j = 0
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if a[i] < b[j]:
        c.append(a[i])
        i = i + 1
    elif b[j] < a[i]:
        c.append(b[j])
        j = j + 1
    elif a[i] == b[j]:
        c.append(a[i])
        c.append(b[j])
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
if i < len(a):
    c.append(a[i:])
if j < len(b):
    c.append(b[j:])
return c
```

Comment: Look up the `.extend()` method of lists.

Comment: Side-note: If this isn't for a class, don't reinvent the wheel. Python already includes the batteries for this: [`heapq.merge` takes an arbitrary number of already sorted iterables, and returns a generator that produces the merged values in sorted order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge). Wrapping in `list` gets the exact results seen here, so replacing `merge(a, b)` with `list(heapq.merge(a, b))` is equivalent (and likely faster, especially as the number of iterables to merge increases).

Answer (score 1):

you would have to add each value individually like this:

```
if i < len(a):
    for k in a[i:]:
        c.append(k)
```

Comment: Repeated `append`ing is wasteful; this is why `extend` exists.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) in your last lines:

```
if i < len(a):
    c.extend(a[i:])
if j < len(b):
    c.extend(b[j:])
```

because `a[i:]` and `b[j:]` are going to be lists

But I don't understand why you won't you use existing methods to your end result:

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
b = [2, 4, 6]

c = a + b

c.sort()

print(c)
```

Won't that work ?

Comment: In theory, concatenating and sorting is inefficient, since the theoretical sorting algorithms can't make use of the existing order. In practice, Python's TimSort hybrid sorting algorithm is designed to handle this scenario quite well (it exploits existing ordering in the inputs), so yes, it's usually fine to just concatenate and sort "from scratch". I suspect the OP is writing this for a class though. If they weren't either concatenation and sorting or `heapq.merge` would be the way to go (latter is usually slightly slower on average, but can stream inputs and outputs to reduce memory costs).